# Does updated provisioning file require new build?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

If I add someone to my adhoc provisioning file, can I just send them the last build and provisioning file?  Or do I need to do another build with the updated provisioning file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'll need to rebuild with the new provisioning file.